# Q. d3.js setup in android

Tags: javascript, android, d3.js

I want to visualized data using collapsible tree provided by d3.js. I'm following the tutorial http://www.appstoremarketresearch.com/articles/d3-js-pie-chart-android-webview/.

Unfortunately, i'm not sure how to start from scratch (installing d3.js) and how to run it in android apps. any reliable references? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the post you linked itself, see section **Make a Pie Chart in an Android Fragment and WebView**:

> To make D3.js charts in an Android application, first download the
>   D3.js source from the D3.js home page.

Then

> 1. In your app project path, create a directory for JavaScript assets: Android-D3jsPieChart/assets/js
> 2. Copy the minified d3.min.js source file from your download into Android-D3jsPieChart/assets/js
> 3. Create a directory for HTML assets: Android-D3jsPieChart/assets/html
> 4. Create file Android-D3jsPieChart/assets/html/piechart.html. Copy this code into the new file:

**D3.js Pie Chart**

The code above allows you to use d3 library from `assets` in your webview. After you have done these setups, you can proceed to any normal `d3.js` tutorials and use them in your webview, for JavaScript files (.js), you can continue to put them in `assets` folder.